# Swift - Firebase Database How to push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an iOS app that needs to send and receive notifications. Right now, my database is a Firebase NoSQL Database. I am using Swift to change variables that are stored in Firebase.

How can I send notification to directly a user using Swift?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what your real aim is. But depending on your use-case, since you're already using a Firebase Database, which means you already have a Firebase Project created, you should make use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

You should first [Setup your iOS Client App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) to receive the push notifications. Follow the guide for more details.

Comment: I want to push notifications device to device. I think, Firebase just let me push notifications from Firebase console. Am i wrong ?

Comment: @DoğuşGüleryüz Using the Firebase Console in just an option. You can still implement your own App Server.

Comment: @AL. How can i implement my own app server? Does it cost me anything? I want to send push notifications to all signed users when i add a new product to firebase database. How can i achieve that?

Comment: @MahrukhRaza It depends on what language you want to use. For the use-case you mentioned, I think you could make use of [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) instead. :)

Comment: @AL. I am using Swift and XCode 8.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Another easy solution which you can code in swift is to use OneSignal(works on ios and android and web) ,you can push notifications to device or devices or segement(groups) in app using their function
I am using it  with firebase works perfectly,great documation 
Just google onesignal ios setup sdk
Where you create a onesignal project and then you use their sdk ,to get a device specific token
Which can be saved in firebase database,and then use their functions to send notifications using the id save in database,i  will supply the code   if needed ,just comment so i can share it
Note:there are alot of other providder but onesignal is free